# Money datatype in Sql-Server

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, jpa

How to map money datatype of SQl-Server with hibernate? Using MoneyConvertor class to map money to SQL-Server but it is not working currently?

Answer (score 1):

From the SQL Server [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-basic-data-types?view=sql-server-2017) covering basic types and their JDBC mappings, we can see that the `money` SQL Server type maps to the `BigDecimal` type in Java.  So, you should setup your Hibernate entities using `BigDecimal` for any fields corresponding to `money` columns in the mapped SQL Server tables.

Comment: But when I am trying to create  table using hibernate it is taking decimal datatype I want  Money datatype.